# Passing a Dictionary object from Obj-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

In my obj-C code base, I'm calling passing a NSDictionary object to a Swift class:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *) application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)dictionaryInfo {
    ...
    [[SwiftClass sharedInfo] setInfo:dictionaryInfo];
    ...
}
```

**SwiftClass.swift**

```
class SwiftClass: NSObject {

    static let sharedInfo = MYQNotificationInfo()

    func setInfo(notification:Dictionary<String,String>) -> Void {
         // runtime error happens before this line
    }
```

}

The app compiles but when I receive a push notification, it crashes.  Using Xcode debugger, I set a breakpoint at the setInfo method within AppDelegate and can see that the push notification is received.  But, once I step into the setInfo method, then the app crashes, never actually making it into the function.  Thus, I suspect that the I'm not setting the parameters within setInfo properly.

Is this an issue where I'm not passing in the Dictionary object in properly?

Comment: Not a Swift expert yet, but it's not a Dictionary<String,String>. It can contain different object types. Have you tried just accepting an NSDictionary in setInfo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDictionary can only be passed to swift as [NSObject: AnyObject] since an NSDictionary can contain objects of any type. Try this:

```
func setInfo(notification:Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>) -> Void {

}
```

Once you receive the dictionary you can retreive a value for a key and downcast that value to it's declared type when needed

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  Actually, I had to use Dictionary<NSObject,NSObject> for the method to function properly.  If you update your answer, I'll accept as solution.

Comment: @Vee just updated. Weird it didn't work with AnyObject though. Can you try to do it as ```Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>``` for the sake of experimentation?

Comment: You're correct... `Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>` worked.  Thanks!